# SQL Query to get column headers as values based on a value

Tags: oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC6gf.png)I have a Table with data in the Input format (as given in attached Image) in Oracle DB.

It needs to be converted to the Output format (as given in attached Image),

To make it clear, if the value is '1' in Columns XX or YY or ZZ, then those need to appear as Role (multiple unique rows - See example for A123) for that ID.
Also, if there are multiple 'Code' values for an ID, then those need to appear as 'Codes: ' separated with comma as can be seen for C123 ID.

Can you please help me out in writing a query to get the required output.

Attached the Input-Output Image (Input_Output.png) since the data may not look in proper format in the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to to write this query below, but havn't any platform to verify the result :) because i'm in train now going to work. Can you try this query :

```
SELECT ID, Name,  'XX' Role FROM yourtable WHERE XX =1 -- To exclude no XX role
union  
SELECT ID, Name, 'YY' Role FROM 
yourtable WHERE YY =1 -- To exclude no YY role
union  
SELECT ID, Name, 'ZZ' Role FROM yourtable WHERE ZZ =1 -- To exclude no ZZ role
union 
SELECT ID, Name, 'Codes: ' || LISTAGG(code, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) "Role" FROM yourtable group by ID, Name;
```

hope this csn help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohamad. 
The query works fine except for the last line using LISTAGG for concatenating. This function is not recognized as maybe because I am using Microsoft SQL server Management studio 2012 to prepare the data, though the input has been taken from Oracle DB.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the type of platform ..
However, you can use the STUFF () function instead of LISTAGG ()
Then you can replace the last query after the last UNION Clause by that:                          
SELECT DISTINCT
ID, NAME,
STUFF ((SELECT ',' + Code
FROM yourtable [TABLE1]
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
AND TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') ROLE
FROM yourtable [TABLE2]       
Help this can help you;)

Answer (score 0):

Final Query used for reference:

SELECT ID, NAME, 'XX' Role FROM TABLENAME WHERE XX=1
union
SELECT ID, NAME, 'YY' Role FROM TABLENAME WHERE YY=1
union
SELECT ID, NAME, 'ZZ' Role FROM TABLENAME WHERE ZZ=1
union 
select ID, NAME, Role='Codes: ', STUFF ((select distinct ','+ Code FROM TABLENAME T1 WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID 
for XML path('')),1,1,''),Role FROM TABLENAME T2